# Energy carried by Electromagnetic Waves

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

The energy density carried by monochromatic planar Electromagnetic Waves is defined as:
$ u = \epsilon_0 E_0^2 cos^2(kz-\omega t + \delta)$

As this wave travels, it carries this energy along with it.

The EM waves also transport energy. The transport of energy flux density which is given by the poynting vector as:

$\mathbf S = cu \hat z$

My doubt is, what do they mean by transport of energy? Shouldn't this energy flux density be the energy reduced (like heat losses) from the energy density *u* which is being carried by the EM waves?The energy flux density and the energy density of EM waves are both different but here, in the book that I'm reading, it makes it feel as if they're similar by then saying:

*For in the time ∆t, a length c∆t passes through area A, carrying with it, energy *u* Ac∆t. (This is the energy in the EM waves). The energy per unit time per unit area, transported by the waves is therefore* *uc*.

What does transport mean here!? My guess is transport (loss) of energy from the system to outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is given by the [Poynting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem):
$$
-\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla\cdot \mathbf{S} + \mathbf{J}\cdot\mathbf{E},
$$
which states that the change of the energy density is due to the energy flux and the Joule's heat. Note that without the last term (the Joule's heat) the equation above is a continuity equation, no different from, e.g., continuity equation for a liquid, with the Poynting vector playing the role of the energy current.

It might help to think of a finite volume, using the integral form of this relation - in this case we are talking about the transport of energy from the selected volume to the outside.